# how to pass a value to a variable that in a other variable

Tags: bash

I am getting a "bad substitution" error while running this code. I want to print the values in `h_1`, `h_2`, `h_3`with a `for` loop.

```
#/!/bin/bash
h_1=12
h_2=13
h_3=14
for ((i=1; i<=2; i++))
 do
  echo "${h_$i}"
done
```

Comment: Why not use arrays? (`h[1]=12 h[2]=13...`)?

Comment: actually i wanted to write without arrays

Comment: if you want to write without arrays because you want it to be portable to other shells that don't have arrays, then you can't use `${!var}` either which is even less portable. You'll have to resort to `eval`. If Michael's answer answers your needs, you should accept it (tick next to it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [indirect parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) with `!`:

```
tmp=h_$i
echo "${!tmp}
```

You have to make the extra `tmp` variable here - you can't just use a string, unfortunately. Indirect expansion works as follows:

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), a level of variable indirection is introduced. Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself. This is known as indirect expansion.

So, above, `${!tmp}` expands to the value of the variable whose name is given by the *value* of the variable `tmp`.

It's also possible to use [`eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-eval) here, but the indirection approach is tidier.

Answer (score 1):

I would use double parentheses form, the so called [`Arithmetic Expansion`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion):

`echo $((h_$i))`

No need of arrays, temporary variables or other fancy stuff. Also, I believe this form is most portable (arithmetic expansion is require by POSIX as far as I know).

From Bash Manual:

> Arithmetic  expansion allows the evaluation of an arithmetic expression and the substitution of the result.  The format for arithmetic expansion is:
>
> ```
>           $((expression))
> ```
>
> The expression is treated as if it were within double quotes,  but  a  double  quote inside  the  parentheses  is  not  treated  specially.  All tokens in the expression undergo parameter expansion,  string  expansion,  command  substitution,  and  quote removal.  Arithmetic expansions may be nested.

Comment: It should be noted that this answer works correctly only when the values are decimal integers. (The fact that this is true for the *example* data in the question doesn’t mean that it is true for this OP’s actual data. Also, other people might find this question as a result of a search.) For example, if `h_1` is `foo`, this will output `0`, and if `h_1` is `0100`, this will output `64` (octal `100` converted to decimal). Other values result in error messages.