# I need to concatenate 2 variables to print the value

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
USER_DEV="abcd"
ENV="DEV"
```

Requirement:
to print the actual value `abcd` by substituting 2 variables as below?
`echo $(USER_$ENV)` should return `abcd`.

I get error as below:

```
USER_ENV: command not found
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Though you should probably use associative arrays instead (e.g., https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/531801/70524)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151507/how-to-pass-a-value-to-a-variable-that-in-a-other-variable

Helped me finding the solution